# How to disable the recently opened snapshot in new tab

Tags: google-chrome

This feature of Chrome is annoying me.

How to disable it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way is to install an extension which replaces the new tab.
Go to chrome store and search for 'new tab' to find one that you like.